# Error with Simple Action Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and trying to set up a super simple database.

I am getting a

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in ProfilesController#index
>
> ProfilesController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not… nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

error and am unsure what is going on. I tried researching but I can not tell what I am doing wrong.

```
#profiles_controller.rb:

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @profiles = Eprofiles.all
  end
end


#routes.rb:

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get 'welcome', to: 'pages#home'
  get 'profiles', to: 'profiles#index'
end

#eprofiles.rb

class Eprofiles < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: could it be `EProfile.all`?  It's rails convention for models to be singular case, not plural

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is self explanatory

```
ProfilesController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"]
```

This means you don't have file `app/views/profiles/index.html.erb`.

Comment: Thank you! I had the file but not in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside `app/models` then locate the file `eprofile.rb`

Inside that file, I would imagine the class name is `class Eprofile`. You want to use the singular name like /u/Ren pointed out.

Also your in your routes, use the suggested format from the rails guides

```
get 'welcome', to: 'pages#home'
get 'profiles', to: 'profiles#index'
```

Be sure to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. Some of the best docs around!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response, I will definitely check out those docs, I've been learning from Code Academy. I have edited my code to match your suggestions but I am still getting the same error!

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what this issue is.  You need the relevant template. Again, the guides outline this in great detail.